# How would I make a command display more then one ARG

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to make a /say command

Using the only code as

`message.channel.send(args[1])`

It then sends Arg one, but then how would I make it do infinite arguments. To extend it.

Answer (score 1):

`args` is an array of string. So you can either do `message.channel.send(args[1]+' '+args[2]);` (Which is not very efficient if want to send more strings.) or do `let statement = args.join(' ');` which would join all the strings in the array with a space and then send `statement`.

Answer (score 0):

Discord.js documentation says that `channel.send()` accepts message content as a string and options as an object.

Reference: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send

Therefore, you cannot extend the `send()` method. You could easily just concatenate the args strings and send them as one message. If you really need a `send()` function that accepts infinite parameters you could create your own implementation the following way:

```
// Delimiter defines the string by which the args strings will be joined
function send(channel, delimiter, ...args) {
    channel.send(args.join(delimiter));
}
send(message.channel, " ", args[1], args[2], args[3]);
```